# How can I do a runtime check of both legs of a union type?

Tags: typescript

I have a variable with the following type:

```
const data: { error: string; } | { property1: string; };
```

(It's the response of an external API, so I can't change it.)

I now want to check which of the two possible types `data` is. I tried this:

```
if (typeof data.error !== 'undefined') { }
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript then complains that

```
Property `error` does not exist on type `{ property1: string }`.
```

How do I get TypeScript to know which of the possible types it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely why TypeScript has [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  You can tell TypeScript how to distinguish between the two consitutents of the union:

```
function dataHasError(data: { error: string; } | { property1: string; }): data is { error: string; } {
  return 'error' in data;
}
```

And then it will narrow types the way you expect inside `if`/`else` clauses:

```
const data: { error: string; } | { property1: string; } = /* API response */;

if (dataHasError(data)) {
  console.log(data.error); // okay
} else {
  console.log(data.property1); // okay
}
```

---

If you often find yourself needing to do this type narrowing by checking for the presence of a key, you can put the following type guard in your library:

```
function hasKey<K extends string>(obj: any, key: K): obj is Record<K, any> {
  return key in obj;
}
```

Then the above can be written like this:

```
if (hasKey(data, 'error')) {
  console.log(data.error); // okay
} else {
  console.log(data.property1); // okay
}
```

---

Relevant note: there is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485) for TypeScript to automatically interpret `key in obj` as a type guard, so that the following would work with no errors:

```
if ('error' in data)) {
  console.log(data.error); // would be okay, currently error
} else {
  console.log(data.property1); // would be okay, currently error
}
```

Currently (as of TypeScript v2.5) that is not part of the language, so a user-defined type guard is the best answer for now.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I wasn't aware of user-defined type guards, but those should of course exactly solve my problem. (And I'm following the Issue - let's hope it makes it in some time.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way I can think of is to use one type with [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) properties instead of union types. Like this:

```
interface ApiResponse = {
    error?: string;
    property1?: string;
}

const errorData: ApiResponse = { error: 'error data' };
const okData: ApiResponse = { property1: 'ok data' };

console.log(typeof errorData.error !== 'undefined'); // true
console.log(typeof okData.error !== 'undefined'); // false

// or even cleaner:

console.log(errorData.error); // truthy
console.log(okData.error); // falsey

console.log(!!errorData.error); // true
console.log(!!okData.error); // false
```

Comment: But in that case I will have to add additional checks everywhere I want to use those properties, even though I know after a first check of whether `data.error` exists which properties are supposed to exist on the object. I've now worked around it by keeping it of the `any` type, and then reassigning it to a properly typed object after the check, but that's still cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I'm currently using. As a workaround, it's fine, but I'd rather use TypeScript's type system properly:

```
const data: any = /* API response */;

if (data.error) {
  const errorData: { error: string; } = data;
  // Do whatever
}

const actualData: { property1: string; } = data;
```